# Difference between these two for loops in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop

Ok, so I'm building an iOS game, and I feel like I have a pretty good grasp on objective-c, but one thing that caused me a **ton** of pain was the reference-errors I got when I used the following for-loop

```
for (MyObject *object in nsMutableArrayOfObjects) {
    // do things with object
}
```

vs.

```
for (int i = 0; i< nsMutableArrayOfObjects.count; i++) {
    // do things with nsMutableArrayOfObjects[i];
}
```

I had a few of these (first loop example) running in sequence and I kept getting the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. I also had some loop nesting, where I would put on inside the other. I'm just really curious to know what the key differences are. I'm assuming the differences have something to do with how they reference the objects in the array.

Comment: It looks like @weichsel is near to a good answer for this.  Not sure why nobody has pointed out that the second loop shouldn't even compile, comparing an int to an NSMutableArray*.  For definitive answer on the exception, post the actual exception (it will say it if it's a case of changing the array while enumerating), and post the code inside the loop.

Comment: also, in the second loop, `nsMutableArrayOfObjects` should be `[nsMutableArrayOfObjects count]`.

Comment: you might want to use the new block syntax for enumeration, http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-blocks-and-enumeration/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example you posted uses Fast Enumeration - The preferred method to enumerate collections.
Apple provides the details in the [Collections Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html).

I am not sure what caused the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in your case (sounds more like a memory management issue). But one thing to keep in mind when using fast enumeration is, that you can't mutate the collection you are enumerating.

Comment: Yes, mutating the array while using fast enumeration. That was the problem.

Comment: Can you explain the differences in more detail? Is fast enumeration a readonly object?

Comment: The key difference is that fast enumeration is a method that uses a struct as buffer to read several objects at a time. Internally it uses objectAtIndex: and a mutation counter to detect changes. A changes throws NSGenericException but it's possible that you removed something and got a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. See these Big Nerd Ranch posts for details: [1](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/1003-fast-enumeration-part-1/), [2](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/1044-fast-enumeration-part-2/), [3](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/1073-fast-enumeration-part-3/).

Comment: Note that mutating while enumerating is still not at all safe with the other type of loop, you just get random impossible to diagnose crashes instead of a nice one with a good message. Your bug isn't fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to do with memory allocation as nsMutableArrayOfObjects is not creating a new pointer in the loop for every Clock cycle, whereas your first loop allocates a new pointer in each Cycle

Beats a wild guess

Answer (score -1):

Both of cycles are correct, we can't answer as we don't see more code... 
Anyway, with EXC_BAD_ACCESS you are probably accessing deallocated object.